# Unable to install Fedora 16 on MacBook Air 2010

Tags: fedora, macbook-air

I am trying to dual boot my MacBook Air 2010 with Fedora 16.  I will settle for Fedora only, but my problem is getting it installed in the first place.

I have tried to install it from USB using the Live CD image and the Normal Installation Media DVD image.

- When using the Live CD it boots into it just fine, but during install the boot partition never installed correctly so attempting a boot once completed just drops me back into grub.
- When using the normal DVD Installation Media image it requires network connectivity and refuses to install (it does not come with the necessary drivers for wireless Internet on the MacBook Air).

Either I need a way to fix the install from the Live CD so it can boot, or a way to get an install image that does not require the Internet (or a setting needed to make sure it does not try to use the Internet to install anything.)

Any help would be appreciated.  I really like Fedora 16 and want to see if it works for me in day-to-day usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora 16 uses Grub 1.99.  As I have learned it uses the syntax of Grub2.  The commands to get fedora to boot from the grub CLI is:

`set root(hd#,#)` // where the first '#' is the hard drive number and the second '#' is the partition number.

```
linux /location-of-linux-kernel root=/mount-path-of-drive.

initrd /location-of-img-file

boot
```

At least this worked for me.  From there I was able to get it set up and fix grub.

Comment: Grub 1.99 *is* GRUB2, just as GRUB 0.97 was GRUB1.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what the solutions was but it was very similar to this.